# .net mvc 2 internationalization text files

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, internationalization

I have a requirement to create internationalization with regular text files (perhaps simple xml). The file needs to be modifiable from a text editor and that changes in it do not require recompilation of the code.

Is there a suggested solution (.net framework's or 3rd party) for such a thing?

Thank you

UPDATE:
I am talking about localization, sorry. What I require is to have a text file, which can be translated and used by application without the need for VisualStudio or recompilation. You change a text file, and it all works.

--MB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any existing solutions, however you can rather easily create your own ResourceProvider.

Here are some good links to get you going:

http://weblogs.asp.net/thangchung/archive/2010/06/25/extending-resource-provider-for-soring-resources-in-the-database.aspx

This [one](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/117287.aspx) is great!

Comment: thanks for your mention.
@Massive: Have you ever seen orchard project? They are use T() for processing all localization. And after that we can plugin any locale that we want. I think it is very good to reference. Please see http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/Creating-global-ready-applications.ashx for more information

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your talking about localization.  I have found this very hard to do after the fact.  We used [Multi Language Software](http://www.jollans.com/tiki/tiki-index.php) to help us add it to existing projects.  It is an ok tool.  I have struggled with it sometimes but not to much.  If anything it can help you come up with a plan to do it better.